# When is it appropriate to use Java interfaces in a board game?

Tags: java, interface

(Note: This more of a theoretical question)

Hi! I have created a working board game called checkers, which is kind of like chess except there are different pieces and rules, and I have done this without using any interfaces. However, I noticed it said in our home assignment instructions that at least one interface should be used.

So I'm wondering when is it appropriate to use an interface in java or more specifically when can it be beneficial in a board game like checkers or chess to use an interface? I'm trying to understand what I could possibly create an interface for (like the movements, drawing to the board, etc.), that at the same time most likely would benefit the program.

Comment: Maybe you could use an interface to model the pieces (having methods like getType(), getAvailableMoves(), isInGame(), etc.)

Comment: Some rules can also be generalized. For instance some people agree on "capturing" enemy pieces which are "behind" and some don't want it. You could have some `CapturingRule` with `canCapture(...);`. OR `interface MovementStrategy { boolean checkMove(Piece p, Board , Place location);}` which is different for "man" and "knights", OR if knights after "catching" enemy piece must "land" directly after it or at any field after it, OR if pieces must catch enemies or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good practice to program to an interface because it formalizes a class to have a required set of methods.  It also makes it possible to gather classes that have implemented a common interface to work together. Imagine that you had many objects which had a setColor method.  Instead of having to set the color individually or thru lists of each type of object, you could have have them do the following:

```
Interface ColorSetter {
   public void setColor(Color color);
}

class Foo implements ColorSetter {
//details omitted
}

class Bar implements ColorSetter {
//details omitted
}

List<ColorSetter> colorSetters = new ArrayList<>();
colorSetters.add(new Foo());
colorSetters.add(new Bar());

// later...
for (ColorSetter c : colorSetters) {
   c.setColor(Color.blue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in any kind of programming language are a contract to specify behavior and abstract communication between 2 parties. When you are designing a software solution you want to build it following best practices and pattern so it will be easier to maintain in the future.

In particular in Java, you have both abstract classes and interfaces. Interfaces declare what a class should do (Interfaces in Java8+ provide ways to specify behavior, actual methods by default but I guess that for your home assignment it is not intended yet.) Since you are developing a game, it could be interested to abstract the functionality that all pieces should handled. They should know how to give their location, to know if they are still active in the game, to know the rules that apply to it. You could also abstract the movements that are executed during the game. Each movement has a specific piece or pieces to which it applies to, knows when it can be executed and how to execute itself and even how to undo it. Your game class could also have a list keeping the history of movements done in the game. That way you could implement an easy way to rewind your game up to a certain point.

You could extend your knowledge by reading too on SOLID principles and checking common software design patterns (e.g. https://refactoring.guru/).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have some abstractions in your code. This means that some bahaviour and data could be generalized and encapsulated in some general type - this could be an interface. You've already mentioned some - like pieces - could there be an interface called Piece? Also with Movements - could there be an interface called Movement?

For instance an Piece interface could have some common methods like:

```
public interface Piece {
    String getName();
    Position getPosition();
    List<Movement> getAvailableMovements();
    void move(Movement movement);
    BufferdImage getImage();
}
```

And the Piece will just implement these methods, so having an piece you know its name, position, image, available movements and you can move it. This is just abstract proposition and may not fit exactly to your desing. But in such a way you could just use Piece instead of specialized class, to serve it in your program.